# PHP doesn't close connections to database (odbc)

Tags: php, odbc, sap-ase

I have an API service that uses `odbc_connect`, `odbc_exec` to load data from database.

I have a 100-rows query that I decided to move to stored procedure. Number of requests of service is about 10 per second.

So what is a problem: when using regular query like `SELECT smthng` everything works fine, when using same `SELECT` in a procedure service starts responding very slow. It causes by a lot of opened connections in a database that doesn't close.

I tried `odbc_close_all` directly after `odbc_exec` and `odbc_fetch` - doesn't help.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM master..sysprocesses
WHERE suid > 0
```

returns about 500 connections.

Also I tried to set

```
SET PROC_RETURN_STATUS OFF
```

Also no help.

Answer (score 1):

Page from [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.odbc-close.php) says:

> This function will fail if there are open transactions on this
>   connection. The connection will remain open in this case.

I think it explains the behavior you are facing.
I think that when stored procedure will finish it's work, `losted` connection will die.
Anyway, some research is needed in your case here.

Comment: But I'm closing connection only after I get the result. Would it fail in this case?

Comment: So.. From PHP you execute call to stored procedure, get the result, close connection, and it does not close (after executing stored procedure)? Are you using transaction in this case?

Comment: Nope, what do you mean "transaction"? My query is `EXECUTE procName $param`;